# Testing Facebook Open Graph API actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

How do you go about testing Facebook's Open Graph API when they don't allow you to? I've created a test app with some actions, to determine whether all of my actions will work correctly, and Facebook have rejected the action with the following message:

> Thank you for your Open Graph submission. Please ensure your
>   submission was intentional and was not created for testing purposes
>   before resubmitting your action. You may view some guidelines in the
>   Submission Checklist:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/checklist/ Please make
>   changes below and re-submit for approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test all you want, just don't submit it for publishing.

Comment: But you must submit it for them to approve the actions, no?

Comment: Yes, eventually. But during development, you can work with your actions all you want, without having to submit them. Note that they will only work for yourself, or other developers of your Facebook app.